# covering of subspaces of $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ be the infinite square grid, i.e., the graph with vertices $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and edges representing all segments connecting points at distance $1$, which is the universal covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$. Let $A, B \subseteq X$ be the two copies of $S^1$, such that $X=A \cup B$ and $A \cap B={x_0}$. For the chosen covering map $p$, describe the induced coverings $p^{-1}(A) \to A$ and $p^{-1}(B) \to B$ (in terms of the classification of connected coverings of $S^1$).

The universal covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$ is:
https://i.imgur.com/vfzIhRMl.png  (sorry if it is written in italian)

Now if we consider for example the map $p^{-1}(A) \to A$ we have $p^{-1}(A)=\mathbb{R} 
 \times\mathbb{Z}$ so why speaks it about connected coverings? Have i to consider only one of the copies of $\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Did you mean $S^1\vee S^1$? $S^1\wedge S^1\cong S^2$ is its own universal covering space, and no other connected ones exist

Comment: It is talking of connected coverings because the whole space, $\Bbb R^2$, is connected. Not because all preimages are connected

Comment: yes sorry i mean $S^1$ wedge $S^1$

Comment: But it says "describe the induced coverings in terms of the classification of connected coverings of $S^1$"

Comment: Can we see the exact wording of the question? I gotta say, I've never heard of induced covering from a subspace, normally we think about induced covering from subgroups of $\pi_1$

Comment: the original test is in italian and i traducted in english, but this is: https://i.imgur.com/A5E5km4l.png[/img]

Comment: One problem that we have is that your $Y$ is **not** simply connected and is not the universal cover. The universal cover is more complicated. It's still a weird question though, since the preimage of $A$ in the universal cover is still homeomorphic with $\Bbb R\times\Bbb Z$ and is not a connected cover.

Comment: I'm sorry, but is $Y$ not contractible? (if we considered it as a graph).

Comment: $Y=\Bbb Z^2$ from your definitions, as far as I can see, and this is not contractible.

Comment: Yes, but if you see the image you can see that we though $Y$ as the graph with two 
bow $a$ and $b$ that are the ones of the wedge of $S^1$. Anyway idk.

Comment: The universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ is the [Cayley graph](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg) of the free group on two generators. The "a" pieces map to one of your $S^1$, the "b" pieces the other. That should help you identify $p^{-1}(A)$ and similarly for $B$.